# React For Loop - Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this for loop in React, that loops through limited number of items, and creates JSX based on that, my render function looks like this:

```
 public render(): React.ReactElement<ITilesProps> {
    let numOfColumns = 2;
    let items = this.state.items;
    let rowsJsx = []
    let initCounter = items.length - numOfColumns;
    let jumper = initCounter > 0 ? numOfColumns : items.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i += jumper) {
      let rowJsx = []

      let limit = (i + jumper - 1) >= items.length ? items.length - 1 : (i + jumper - 1)
      for (let j = i; j <= limit; j++) {
        let props = {
          previewImages: [
            {
              url: items[j].EncodedAbsUrl,
              previewImageSrc: items[j].EncodedAbsUrl,
              imageFit: ImageFit.cover,
              width: 318,
              height: 196
            }]
        }
        rowJsx.push(<SingleCardContainer><DocCard previewImageProps={props} ></DocCard></SingleCardContainer>)
      }
      rowsJsx.push(<TileRow>{rowsJsx}</TileRow>)
    }

    return (
      <div className="ms-Grid" dir="ltr">
        {rowsJsx}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

What I am creating, is a row of tiles, the first loop is looping through items, and skipping the # of tiles in each row, the second loop is looping through tiles in each row, creating the JSX for it, and adding it to the array of tiles in each row, which in turn is added to the all rows JSX array.

Any idea why this might give an error?

Thanks.

Comment: `rowsJsx.push(<TileRow>{rowsJsx}</TileRow>)`  That looks like a potential candidate.  I've a feeling you meant to put `{rowJsx}` there instead.

Comment: @Keith each row must have a wrapper (like bootstrap), which contains the class for the width, etc.. so that's the TileRow component, and in there I wanna add all the rows I had

Comment: Oh yes, I just noticed that @Keith thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Would you like to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it was just simple typo..  Easy done.

```
rowsJsx.push(<TileRow>{rowsJsx}</TileRow>)
```

In the above you have accidentally added  `rowsJsx` instead of `rowJsx` , so your accumulated rows are getting added each time.

```
rowsJsx.push(<TileRow>{rowJsx}</TileRow>)
```